# set up logging to email a 403 error (CSRF error) in Django

Tags: django

Am looking for a way to get 403 errors to trigger an admin error email with the full stacktrace and request dump - similar to a 500 error would.

Specifically how can I add it to my logging config the CSRF middleware emits a WARNING level message. But I don't want all django.request warning messages, only the 403s..

Comment: Have you read this page? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/ is more useful, but still not that clear

Answer (score 1):

One way which will work is to use a custom 403 handler view, and call `mail_admins` from there:

In your `urls.py`, add

```
handler403 = 'myproj.myviews.error403'
```

In `myviews.py`:

```
def error403(request):
    """
    Custom handling of 403s, to send an email to the admins
    """

    mail_admins(
        "403 alert", 
        "%s got hit in the face with Forbidden shovel" % request.user
    )
    # NB: this isn't a robust reporting message as 
    #may not be partic suited to anonymous users

    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Ideally, your mail needs to be queued and sent async to prevent your user having to wait, but that's a separate thing.

Comment: good work around - ideally I'd like to add it to my logging config, but if not, this will also do the trick.

Comment: With an appropriately set up logging, you could raise logger.critical() instead of mail_admins in the view and that would ue the logger setup to report it